# R: Extracting specific columns works weird, any thought?

Tags: r

I am using a basic script in Rstudio to read in files, extract only specific columns and save the new data frame into an Excel file. The script is working well for half of the files, but for the remaining ones, the columns extracted are filled with "TRUE" values instead of the real values.

This is what it looks like for half of the files (working fine):

[image: 1]

This is what it looks like for the other half (not working):

[image: 2]

The only pattern that I see is that this happens for session 2 only (the files either belong to recordings from session 1 or session 2 in my experiment). I checked the headers of the columns, and they all match together, so it cannot be an issue of mislabelled headers.

Here is the code below:

```
library(readxl)
library(readr)
library(writexl)


P1S1HTN = read_xls("/Users/zala/Desktop/edat_exported/P1S1C1HTN.xls", col_names = TRUE)

P1S2HTN = read_xls("/Users/zala/Desktop/edat_exported/P1S2C1HTN.xls", col_names = TRUE)

P2S1HTN = read_xls("/Users/zala/Desktop/edat_exported/P2S1C1HTN.xls", col_names = TRUE)

P2S2HTN = read_xls("/Users/zala/Desktop/edat_exported/P2S2C1HTN.xls", col_names = TRUE)

P3S1HTN = read_xls("/Users/zala/Desktop/edat_exported/P3S1C1HTN.xls", col_names = TRUE)

P3S2HTN = read_xls("/Users/zala/Desktop/edat_exported/P3S2C1HTN.xls", col_names = TRUE)

P4S1HTN = read_xls("/Users/zala/Desktop/edat_exported/P4S1C1HTN.xls", col_names = TRUE)

P4S2HTN = read_xls("/Users/zala/Desktop/edat_exported/P4S2C1HTN.xls", col_names = TRUE)

P5S1HTN = read_xls("/Users/zala/Desktop/edat_exported/P5S1C1HTN.xls", col_names = TRUE)

P5S2HTN = read_xls("/Users/zala/Desktop/edat_exported/P5S2C1HTN.xls", col_names = TRUE)

P6S1HTN = read_xls("/Users/zala/Desktop/edat_exported/P6S1C1HTN.xls", col_names = TRUE)

P6S2HTN = read_xls("/Users/zala/Desktop/edat_exported/P6S2C1HTN.xls", col_names = TRUE)

P7S1HTN = read_xls("/Users/zala/Desktop/edat_exported/P7S1C1HTN.xls", col_names = TRUE)

P7S2HTN = read_xls("/Users/zala/Desktop/edat_exported/P7S2C1HTN.xls", col_names = TRUE)

P8S1HTN = read_xls("/Users/zala/Desktop/edat_exported/P8S1C1HTN.xls", col_names = TRUE)

P8S2HTN = read_xls("/Users/zala/Desktop/edat_exported/P8S2C1HTN.xls", col_names = TRUE)


allDataS1 = rbind(P1S1HTN, P2S1HTN,P3S1HTN, P4S1HTN, P5S1HTN,  P6S1HTN, P7S1HTN, P8S1HTN) 
allDataS2 = rbind( P1S2HTN, P2S2HTN, P3S2HTN,  P4S2HTN, P5S2HTN,  P6S2HTN,  P7S2HTN,  P8S2HTN) 

smallData_SR2= allDataS2[allDataS2$`Procedure[Block]` == "SR",c("ExperimentName","Subject", "Session", "SessionDate", "Procedure[Block]", "ColourPairs.RESP", "ColourPairs.RT", "StimulusDisplayed[Trial]") ]
smallData_SR1= allDataS1[allDataS1$`Procedure[Block]` == "SR",c("ExperimentName","Subject", "Session", "SessionDate", "Procedure[Block]", "ColourPairs.RESP", "ColourPairs.RT", "StimulusDisplayed[Trial]") ]


write_xlsx(smallData_SR1,"/Users/zala/Desktop/edat_exported/All_data_files/All_EEG_SR1.xlsx")
write_xlsx(smallData_SR2,"/Users/zala/Desktop/edat_exported/All_data_files/All_EEG_SR2.xlsx")
```

Do you have an idea of what could be happening?

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Are the columns filled with TRUE entirely empty in those particular spreadsheets? Not available columns aka NA are logical values in R and might get replaced by TRUE. Furthermore, usually only the first few lines were used to guess the column type

Comment: @danlooo - Good thought although the default for `read_xls()` is to guess from the first 1000 rows.

Comment: No, those columns are filled with the same kind of values as for the "good" files, which makes it even harder to understand why it does not work for them.

Comment: @RitchieSacramento This might be the problem then. Is there a way to "expand" the read_xls() search to, let's say, 3000 rows?

Comment: @Morgane - you can use the argument `guess_max = 3000`

Comment: I added guess_max = inf and it worked fine. Many thanks!